# PostgreSQL: how to format date without using to_char()?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have this PHP-script which I'd like to keep unchanged:

```
$display = array(
    'QDATETIME',
    'ID',
    'NAME',
    'CATEGORY',
    'APPSVERSION',
    'OSVERSION',
);

$sql = sprintf("
    select %s from quincytrack
    where qdatetime > (now() - interval '2 day') and
    qdatetime <= now()",
    join(', ', $display));
$sth = $pg->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($args);
```

My problem is that QDATETIME is printed as **2010-12-18 15:51:37** while I need it as **2010-12-18**. I know I could call **to_char(QDATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as QDATETIME**, but would prefer to find some other way to affect the date output format...

Using PostgreSQL 8.4.5 under CentOS 5.5 Linux / 64 bit.

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: `TO_CHAR` is specially designed for formatting the output. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach than relying on the database for date formatting would be to rely on PHP for this.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['column']));
```

This both solves your initial problem (of confusing the join statement when building your query), and also gives you a lot more flexibility (eg, maybe later a user can set a preference for preferred date format), and more scalability (the more work you can do in PHP which is unlimitedly horizontally scalable, the better).

Answer (score 2):

Just CAST to datatype DATE:

```
SELECT
    CAST('2010-12-18 15:51:37' AS DATE);
```

Comment: This depends on the `datestyle` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your PHP script, you can try adjusting [`datestyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) configuration parameter.

I would recommend that you just change your PHP script though. Changing a global server configuration might affect other stuff currently running on your server.